# Safe I/O voltage levels for Xilinx SP605

Tags: xilinx, spartan-6

## Context

I recently got an SP605 Evaluation board from Xilinx, that sports a Spartan-6 FPGA. (check out [this link](http://xilinx.com/sp605)).

This board has a bunch of User I/O and the two I'm most interested right are the two generic I/O SMA connectors on the top right of the board. As a first test, I tried to use them as output, setting them HIGH when a button was pressed on the board. On a scope, this gives out `2.5V`.

[image: Rough FPGA-SP605 settings]

The highlighted block (red) contains the SMA I am talking about. It is connected to the `Bank 0 @ 2.5V`, which matches what I see on the scope.

## Question(s)

I cannot find a reference for the SP605's ratings, just for the Spartan-6 and even though the latter can accept / drive `3.3V` I/O, I don't think this can be extended to the SP605.

1. Is it safe to assume that a `2.5V` INPUT won't fry anything? (assume of course no voltage spikes/overshooting)
2. Is there a way to change these I/O levels or are they locked in some way on the board?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Yes, FPGA IOs are usually powered per bank, on your board BANK0 is powered by 2.5V, so will be fine with 2.5V in. However you will want to check the datasheet for the high/low voltage threshold. Don't forget to check what voltage each bank is working at before you connect things up though! Bank0 is 2.5 but there no reason why the other banks are not at 1.8 (or even 1.2) or up to 5V depending on the development board.

2) I wouldn't expect so on a dev board such as the one you have, however you may be able to bodge it on the PCB if you check out the schematics and know what you're doing.